# Cocoon, or Nested Form gems, method undefined errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cocoon-gem

I tried adding both Cocoon and Nested Form gems.After doing a bundle install and server restart, Whenever I try to use the built in helper methods(ex. link_to_add_association for cocoon, or link_to_add for nested form) I get the "undefined method" error. I am running rails 3.2 what is the issue here

Comment: Could you add some more details/code? `link_to_add_association` is a view helper, if the gem is in the bundle it would be very hard to go wrong. But if you are using the wrong association name, or not in the context of a correct form, it will give you the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'object' for nil:NilClass`, which without further details from you might be the problem you are having.

Comment: Just took a look this morning and surprisingly it was working somewhat and I was able to get it fully working after that. I suspect it was some wierd issue that didnt fix until I happened to restart my computer and therefore the prax/pow servers with it. I appreciate your help though